# Conditional aggregation query with a group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a system where users log in from different companies. I'm trying to run a query to see the number of active users vs total number of users for each company.

`Users` table:

`userID`, `companyID`, `lastLogin`

Desired Output:

`companyID`, `totalCompanyUsers`, `numUsersWhoLoggedInWithinLastMonthFromCompany`

Query attempt:

```
SELECT companyID, COUNT(userID) AS `numUsersWhoLoggedInWithinLastMonth`
FROM Users
WHERE IFNULL(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, lastLogin, NOW()),- 1) = 1
GROUP BY companyID;
```

I'm struggling to figure out how to have two aggregation functions, where one is conditional.

Comment: Not only column's name, but add some sample data and desired result.

Comment: Perfectly good question, an attempt was made and it's easy to visualise what is required based on the column names and the attempt that was made. Not all questions need sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pretty close, you just need to put the conditions inside the aggregate function for the conditional aggregation you want to perform:

```
SELECT
companyID, 
COUNT(userID) AS `totalCompanyUsers`,
SUM(CASE 
  WHEN 
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MONTH, lastLogin, NOW()) < 1 THEN 1 
  ELSE 0
END
) AS `numUsersWhoLoggedInWithinLastMonth`
FROM Users
GROUP BY companyID;
```

The results are still grouped by `companyID`, but the second aggregation function performs a sum of 1s and 0s depending on whether the user logged in within the last month or not.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, that unfortunately returns `0` for all `numUsersWhoLoggedInWithinLastMonth`

Comment: I'm not sure if this would effect it, but users who have never logged in, ie some not active users, have a `lastLogin` value of `Null`

Comment: I swapped your `<` for a `>`  and it is now working ! thanks!!

Comment: scrap that I was being stupid, yours works perfectly, thanks