# How do I select how many pantients every doctor has?

Tags: sql, join, select, group-by, count

I have a table of Visits on the Hospital, included DoctorID, PacientID, Date.... 
I did like this but I recieved an error.

```
SELECT 
d.DoctorID, COUNT(v.DoctorID)
FROM Visits v
left join Doctors d on  v.DoctorID=d.DoctorID
```

Answer (score 2):

You care missing the `group by`:

```
SELECT d.DoctorID, COUNT(v.DoctorID)
FROM Doctors d LEFT JOIN
     Visits v 
     ON v.DoctorID = d.DoctorID
GROUP BY d.DoctorID;
```

In addition, you presumably want the `LEFT JOIN` starting with `Doctors` so you keep all doctors.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is missing a `GROUP BY` clause. Also I do not see the need for a `JOIN`. If you want the count of (distinct) `patientsID`s per `doctorID`, you can get that information directly from the `visit` table, like so:

```
select doctorID, count(distinct patientID) from visits group by doctorID
```

Or, if you also want to see doctors that have no patients:

```
select d.doctorID, count(distinct v.patientID) 
from doctors d
left join visits v on v.doctorID = d.doctorID
group by d.doctorID
```

Answer (score 0):

[Live demo on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a790382c94d74343586db88b2804b897)

You are missing `GroupBy` clause.

So you can fix it in this way

```
SELECT d.Name, COUNT(v.DoctorID) AS PantientCount
FROM Doctors d
LEFT JOIN Visits v ON d.DoctorId = v.DoctorId
GROUP BY d.Name
```

You can also using [Conditional aggregation query with a group by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38216640/conditional-aggregation-query-with-a-group-by) like below.

```
SELECT d.Name, SUM(CASE WHEN v.CustomerId IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS PantientCount
FROM Doctors d
LEFT JOIN Visits v ON d.DoctorId = v.DoctorId
GROUP BY d.Name
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @Patrycja Bobek